# PHP MySQL update multiple row with check box

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update checked values in MySQL with PHP

```
<?php

require "../../../../config.php";


if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])) {
    try {

        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $ck_id = $_POST['ck_id'];

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ck_id); $i++) {
            $sql = "UPDATE form_eg208 SET status=:status where ck_id IN (:ck_id)";
            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(':status', $status[$i]);
            $statement->bindParam(':ck_id', $ck_id[$i]);

            $statement->execute();
        }

    } catch (PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }


    if ($statement->rowcount() >= 0) {

        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="flash- 
                msg">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times; 
                    </a>
                  <h4> <strong>Success!</strong> Insert Record  
                 Successfully</h4>
                  </div>';

    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" id="flash- 
                   msg">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times; 
                         </a>
                 <h4> <strong>Failed!</strong> Duplicate BGLPARTNO</h4>
                    </div>';
    }
}

?>
```

my html code is

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['cid'];

try {

    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $j = 1;
    $sql = "CALL view_eg208 (:bglpartno)";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':bglpartno', $id);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();

}

foreach ($result as $row1)
?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:40px;">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="needs-validation" novalidate>

                        <div class="table-responsive m-t-40">

                            <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">

                                <thead class="thead-dark">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No.</th>
                                    <th>Activity</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:center;">Status</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php

                                if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) {
                                    foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="ck_id[]" class="filled-in chk-col-blue"
                                                       name="ck_id[]" value="<?php echo escape($row["ck_id"]); ?>"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="color:black"><?php echo escape
                                                ($row["activity_name"]); ?></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="form-group has-danger"
                                                     style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                                    <input type="text" id="status[]" name="status[]" maxlength="100" class="form-control" value="<?php echo escape($row["status"]);?>" autocomplete="off" required="required">
                                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        Please provide a Inputs.
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    <?php }
                                }
                                $connection = null;
                                ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

When I update all the values then it works correctly  but when single value then it updates the value of first box into that box which I selected. Please help me to solve this

Comment: please make sure that you are displaying checkboxes properly if checkbox status is already updated then you need to display it as checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make your checkbox input like this so you get the right `status` for the right `ck_id` index :

```
if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { 

    foreach ($result as $i => $row) { ?>

        <tr>

            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ck_id[]"class="filled-in chk-col-blue" 
                name="ck_id[<?php echo $i ?>]" value="<?php echo escape ($row["ck_id"]);?>"/> 
            </td>   
            <td style="color:black"><?php echo escape 
                ($row["activity_name"]);?></td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group has-danger" 
                style="margin-bottom: 0;">                   
                    <input type="text" id="status[]" name="status[<?php echo $i ?>]" 
                        maxlength="100" class="form-control" value="<? 
                        php echo escape ($row["status"]);?>" autocomplete="off" 
                        required="required" >                  
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please provide a Inputs.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>    

        </tr>   

    <?php
    }
}
```

Also try to use `foreach` instead of `for` loops :

```
    try {

        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $ck_id = $_POST['ck_id'];

        // for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ck_id); $i++) {
        foreach ($ck_id as $i => $value) {
            $sql = "UPDATE form_eg208 SET status=:status where ck_id IN (:ck_id)";
            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(':status', $status[$i]);
            $statement->bindParam(':ck_id', $ck_id[$i]);

            $statement->execute();
        }

    } catch (PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: please refer to this help guide : [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)